# Nativescript-vue Font Icon - Image Tag

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have read the following code from nativescript core documentation.

```
<Image src="font://&#xf51e;" stretch="none" class="fas"></Image>
```

I want to use Image tag for displaying icons, but when i tried the previous code with **NATIVESCRIPT-VUE**, nothing appears.

My Code is the following:

```
<Label text="hola" textWrap="true" />
<Label class="fas" style="font-size: 50em; color: red" text.decode="&#xf7aa;" />
<Label class="fas" style="font-size: 50em; color: blue" text.decode="&#xf51e;" />
<Label class="far" style="font-size: 50em; color: orange" text.decode="&#xf2bb;" />
<Label class="fab" style="font-size: 50em; color: black" text.decode="&#xf2b3;" />
<Image src="font://&#xf51e;" stretch="none" class="fas"></Image>
```

The icons with the label tag, works perfect. However, the Image tag with icon does not work.

Documentation Link : [Here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/icon-fonts)

**Here is my project structure**

[image]

PlayGround Sample: [Link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=fe24Mi)

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my end, please make sure you have copied the font to your fonts folder. If you still have issues, please share a Playground sample.

Comment: Are you using nativescript-vue? It works fine in nativescript core

Comment: I just add the palyground sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the CSS definition for `fas`

```
.fas {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "fa-solid-900";
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

It works!

```
<Label class="fas" style="font-size: 50em; color: red"
                text.decode="&#xf7aa;" />
<Image src.decode="font://&#xf7aa;" stretch="none"
                class="fas">
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=fe24Mi&v=2)

Comment: It is true. I was also forgetting the **src.decode**. Thanks!!!